# Maximo Anywhere login

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

Hello im new in maximo anywhere. i installed maximo anywhere 7.6 then i installed maximo anywhere apps to my android emulator bu i get an error when i click login.

**Error is :**

The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.

[Screenshot from emulator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEn3W.png)

Also i get an error in mxserver logs. Error log is :

> [10/18/16 14:23:53:655 FET] 0000015b filter        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper doFilter SRVE8109W: Uncaught exception thrown by filter HSTSFilter: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/api/AssetDataManager/android/query
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor._processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:949)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:930)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:484)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>       at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3878)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:461)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:528)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:314)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)

i would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I changed properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your app is pointing to the Worklight Server? Turn on connection.settings in your app-feature.properties file, rebuild and redeploy the app, and confirm your Connection Settings within the Android app to make sure you're pointing to the right hostname/port and MobileFirst context.  Are you sharing your MXServer process between Worklight/MobileFirst and Maximo?

If so, make sure that you have deployed the AssetDataManager app to that Worklight/MobileFirst server, the error says that when the app tried to contact the MobileFirst server at that path "/apps/services/api/AssetDataManager/android/query", it couldn't load any data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes im sure that connection settings are true. Because if i turn off server, application says i cant connect to server. I can't find the path (/apps/services/api/AssetDataManager/android/query). How can i deploy AssetDataManager app to that Worklight/MobileFirst server?

Thank you for your answer.